Generic inference issue
I have code that looks like this:
type Getter<T> = () => T;
type GetterOrStatic<T> = T | Getter<T>;

type Input<T> = T extends {[K: string ]: string} ? { [K in keyof T]: GetterOrStatic<T[K]>} : T;

declare function f<T extends {[K: string ]: string} | string>(value: Input<T>): T;

const x = f({ x : 'x'}); // <-- correctly inferred as `{ x: string }`

const y = f({y: (): string => 'y'}); // <-- I expect it to be `{ y: string }` but it is `string | { [K: string]: string }`

Playground
I expect, of course, the y element to be inferred as { y: string }.
Edit: some people asked about, the string argument option, in case of f('x') I expect it to be inferred as string, not the literal 'x'. I included this because in my real use case the function can accept more than just records, so it was important to me to reflect that. (Also if you only include extend { [K: string]: string } you have another issue where f({ x: 'x' }) is inferred as { x: 'x' }, which is not the desired result here. See later).
Edit 2: Please note that another requirement here is that the generic itself (which is consumer facing - the consumer can write it explicitly) needs to describe the returned value (i.e., the values of a record must be strings, not Getters). So a solution in which the generics has a constraint of extends string | { [K: string]: GetterOrStatic<string> } is not valid here unfortunately.
One thing I tried is to use overloading like so:
declare function f<T extends {[K: string ]: string}>(value: { [K in keyof T]: GetterOrStatic<T[K]> }): T;
declare function f<T extends {[K: string ]: string} | string>(value: Input<T>): T;

However, that causes the first example (x) to be inferred as { x: 'x' } instead of {x: string}. I'm guessing because TypeScript based that I want further type narrowing since the condition is now only {[K: string ]: string} in the first overflow option.
I found that I can work around this (in quite a "hacky" way) by doing this:
declare function f<T extends {[K: string ]: string} | {}>(value: { [K in keyof T]: GetterOrStatic<T[K]> }): T;
declare function f<T extends {[K: string ]: string} | string>(value: Input<T>): T;

Now this example works, but there are other issues with it in similar but more nuanced usecases:

If GetterOrStatic (or whatever else I use there), could only accept strings), there is a type error on T[K]. Playground
If I use arrays instead of objects, this forces me to use an extend condition to the argument to infer the type of the array, which brings us back to the original issue. Playground

Incidentally, both of these issues are relevant in my actual use case (which is too complicated to post here, so I tried to simplify for the purposes of this post).
How can I accomplish what I want here?

To clarify - is the idea that you will pass in an object whose properties are either values or getter functions, and f will return an object where all the getter functions are replaced with their return values?

I think it would be very helpful if you [edit] to describe exactly what you're trying to do with the example function, because right now there are apparent use cases you're not showing, like if you call f("abc"); should that return string or "abc" or something completely different?

(see prev comment). I'd definitely try to make it so that the input to f is just of some generic type T appropriately constrained, and then compute the return type. That will be a lot better than trying to poke at the edges of inference. Maybe as shown in this playground link but I don't know without a good set of test cases in the question. Please [edit] to provide them.

@kaya3 that is one example of what this function might do. However, the implementation of the function is not important to this question as I'm asking about typing. My real use case is more complicated than that, so this examples is merely a sensible simplification of it.

@jcalz Your examples work like I want except the fact that I want to allow users to type an explicit generic, in which case I want them to the type the return value, as it's a better descriptor for consumer intent in my use case. I will edit the question to explain this.

Note that at some point you will start adding constraints that make what you're trying to do either impossible or too difficult to be done in a non-fragile way. You can't exert complete control over TypeScript's inference algorithm.

@jcalz Do you mean my requirements are impossible to satisfy..?

I mean if you keep adding requirements to this question, eventually they will almost surely be impossible or extremely difficult to satisfy. I can work around this new constraint by using an overload, one which allows a user-defined type argument and one which does not, so we can get the two different behaviors, as shown in this playground link. Is this what you want now or are there more use cases to worry about?

@jcalz This is the best answer so far and probably a good compromise that I will use if I can't find anything better (As this still feels a little hacky). I'll still wait for other people to see if there is another solution I can't think of. Thanks!

Right now it's just a comment, not an answer. If you do decide you want to accept such an answer I'll write one up. Just let me know, no rush.

@jcalz I think you should go ahead and make this an answer, as it technically satisfies all requirements and no one else has suggested a better alternative.  I will mark as accepted answer when you do.

In general, the more complicated a generic type function F<T> is, the less likely TypeScript can successfully infer T from a value of type F<T>. Furthermore, even when TypeScript can successfully infer some type argument T, it might not be exactly what you were expecting. If F<T> is T extends string ? T : { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | (() => T[K]) } and you pass in a value {x: "x"}, TypeScript is perfectly at liberty to decide that T is {x: "x"} as opposed to {x: string}. It could even choose {x: unknown}, if it wanted to... there are a lot of heuristic rules about which inference candidates to consider.
Your choices are: you could either accept the inference you get, or you can change the type from which you infer and compute your desired type from it.
Right now your function looks more or less like
declare function f<T extends string | (object & { [K in keyof T]: string })>(
  u: T extends string ? T : { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | (() => T[K]) }
): T

where I inlined some of your type definitions and replaced the index signature with a mapped type over the keys. That function is perfectly fine if you want users to manually specify a type argument for T when they call the function.
But you're not happy with how T is inferred. Instead of trying to force TypeScript to change how it infers things for the case function f<T>(u: F<T>): T, it's much easier to invert that type function yourself. If you can manually write a type function G<U> such that G<F<T>> is equivalent to T, then you can rewrite the function as function f<U>(u: U): G<U>. Now TypeScript only has to infer U from a value of type U, and that's very easy. Furthermore if you don't like the inference because it's too specific, you can write G<U> to be less specific.  Here's how that version of the function would look:
declare function f<U extends string | (
  object & { [K in keyof U]: string | (() => string) }
)>(
    u: U
): U extends string ? string : 
   { [K in keyof U]: U[K] extends (() => infer R) ? R : U[K] };

You can verify manually that G<F<T>> is the T you want it to be; if u is a string then it's string, otherwise if u is an object whose properties are strings-or-string-getters, then T is an object with any getters resolved to their return types.

Personally I'd want to switch to that version entirely. But you have a requirement were users can optionally pass in T.  So we would need a hybrid approach if we want to have the best of both worlds. Here's one way to do that:
// inference of generic
declare function f<U extends string | (
    object & { [K in keyof U]: string | (() => string) }
), Dummy>(
    u: U
): U extends string ? string :
    { [K in keyof U]: U[K] extends (() => infer R) ? R : U[K] };

// manual specification of generic
declare function f<T extends string | (object & { [K in keyof T]: string })>(
    u: T extends string ? T : { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | (() => T[K]) }
): T

This is an overloaded function with two call signatures. The first call signature is the one for inference, and will be selected when someone calls f(u).  But it now takes two type arguments, the second of which is a dummy argument whose point is just to prevent it from being selected when a user calls f<T>(u) with a manual T.  So when someone calls f<T>(u), the second call signature is selected.

Okay, let's test it out:
const x = f({ x: 'x' });
//    ^? const x: { x: string; }

const y = f({ y: (): string => 'y' });
//    ^? const y: { y: string; }

const z = f("a");
//    ^? const z: string;

const w = f({ a: "abc", b: () => "def" })
//    ^? const w: { a: string; b: string; }

f(1) // error
f({ a: 123, b: () => 456, c: false }); // error

f<string>("z"); // okay
f<{ y: string }>({ y() { return "z" } }); // okay
f<{ x: string }>({ x: "x" }); // okay
f<{ a: string, b: string }>({ a: "abc", b: () => "def" }) // okay

Looks good. The return types are inferred how you want, there are errors on incorrect inputs, and when you manually specify the return type as a type argument, the input is checked against it.
Playground link to code

I feel like this is what you are looking for, but it also feels like too simple of an answer, so maybe it's a miss..
type F<T> = T extends string | number | boolean ? T :{
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends () => infer R ? R : T[K];
};

declare function f<T>(value: T): F<T>;

const ex1 = f("wow")  // string
const ex2 = f({ x : 'x'}); // { x: string }
const ex3 = f({y: (): string => 'y'}); // { y: string }

Here is a playground showing how it works.
https://tsplay.dev/WJP4rN
Example of Narrower Consumer type
type NotGetter = string | number | boolean | Record<string, string | number | boolean>
type ConsumerF<T extends NotGetter> = F<T>


Here is a playground showing the use of the ConsumerF
https://tsplay.dev/wE65ZN
If the string literal is never the type you want
We can update the F generic like this to broaden back to string types.
type Primitive = string | number | boolean;
type FReturn<T> = T extends string ? string : T;
type F<T> = T extends Primitive
  ? T
  : {
      [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends () => infer R ? FReturn<R> : T[K];
    };

declare function f<T>(value: T): F<T>;

const ex8 = f({ x: () => "bob" }); // { x: string }

https://tsplay.dev/NdxjkN

See "Edit 2" - I want my generic to represent the returned type because it's consumer facing (consumer can explicitly write it)

I don't believe "Edit 2" is possible.  I read that as you want anyone using the generic type directly to be limited only be able to pass string | Record<string, string> but not ()=>string .    I think you will need a unique or narrowed type for the consumer.  An overload just makes both types posible, you want the consumer to only be able to use a narrower type.  But if anyone knows if it is possible it is @jcalz

In your example, a consumer using your consumer type can't do this: f<{ name: string}>(name: () => 'Shahar'), and I expect them to be able to do it.

Oh gotcha.  That pattern wasn't clear to me.

Would you ever want to the type to be the string literal?  If not, it's  simple tweak to have ()=> 'Shahar'  return string

I want the consumers to be able to explicitly specify a string literal in the generic, but when the generic is inferred it should prefer inferring strings.

What about passing a flag "isLiteral" do allow the user to choose between literal and non-literal types ?
